# cannot get assets(images/fonts) loaded properly in deployed application

Tags: ember-cli

So I am trying to deploy my ember app in wamp server. I have all my assets within public/assets folder. The folder structure is like :

```
public
    -assets
          -images
          -fonts
```

When I run things using command

```
ember server
```

a server is ran at port 4200 and when I browse there everything runs fine, the images and fonts are loaded properly. Now I wanted to deploy this application in wamp server. To do this, I modified the baseURL in config/environment.js as:

```
baseURL: 'myProj/'//since the app will we put in www/myProj folder
```

then I compiled my project and moved everything within dist/ folder into the www/myProj folder. But when I browse to my localhost/myProf, I cannot see any of the images or the fonts are not loaded. But the css which is in assets folder is loading fine, its only not able to load fonts and images within assets folder. Its trying to fetch those images like this

```
http://localhost:8085/assets/images/chevron-down-16.png
```

but the correct path should have been:

```
http://localhost:8085/myProj/assets/images/chevron-down-16.png
```

in my hbs files I use

```
`<img src="/assets/images/..." />`
```

How can I get this to work?? Any help will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I had to just do this `<img src="assets/images/..." />` ie. get rid of the first slash to makes images work. But still running into issues in css where I had to use background image, something like this does not work

```
 //BOTH DO NOT WORK
.form-container {
    //background: url("/assets/images/brushed_alu.png") repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box transparent;
    background: url("assets/images/brushed_alu.png") repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box transparent;
}
```

Ok i just got bit confused, since the css is within assets folder already, I didn't need to give the path starting from assets, so all I had to do was :

```
.form-container {

    background: url("images/brushed_alu.png") repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box transparent;
}
```

Ahh small things bite you the most!

Comment: any ideas how you get ember-cli to access images outside of the project? If I give it a base path of '../foo' I get errors of the form **ontent Security Policy directive**  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758524/how-to-set-up-an-external-server-root-for-ember-cli-server

Comment: I have to do this because in prod I am using a cms and I need my paths to start with /content as that is where all the files come from in the CMS