# How to set up an external server root for ember-cli server

Tags: ember-cli

I am phasing ember into a project that has its content linking from the server root (as it is in prod).

E.g I have a html files with links like this:

```
  <img src="/content/foo.svg">
```

How can I set up ember cli so that when I run ember server these URL's will work, without having to move the ember-cli project to the directory in my file system containing /content. I could get round this by moving content into the ember folder but don't want to do this at present..

my folder structure:

```
/content
/anotherFolder
     /theEmberCliApp
          /app
          /etc etc..
```

but when I run it I get this error:

```
[Report Only] Refused to connect to 'ws://127.0.0.1:35729/livereload' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' ws://localhost:35729 ws://0.0.0.0:35729".
 livereload.js?ext=Chrome&extver=2.0.9:193__connector.Connector.Connector.connect livereload.js?ext=Chrome&extver=2.0.9:193Connector livereload.js?ext=Chrome&extver=2.0.9:176LiveReload livereload.js?ext=Chrome&extver=2.0.9:862(anonymous function) livereload.js?ext=Chrome&extver=2.0.9:1074(anonymous function)
```

I think the issue is this:  **baseURL: '../../'** how can I get round this? For other non ember sites I just point apaches httpdconfig to the location of the parent of content, but I don't want to stick the whole ember cli project in there.

my environment.js:

```
/* jshint node: true */

module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'ember-app',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '../../',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      }
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    }
  };



  if (environment === 'production') {

  }

  return ENV;
};
```

Comment: In the file `config/environment.js` change `host:` to the desired url in each env.

Comment: I don'have a host: property..  where should I add it?

Comment: *baseURL << change that

Comment: I added **
    baseURL: '../../',** but no luck, the resources are not found in the browser

Comment: I've added a bunch of edits :)